# JSP: problems with multiple queries and generated keys

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, netbeans

I have this java method:

```
public boolean insertAuthor(String userid, String password){
    try{
        String query1 = "INSERT INTO user (id, firstName, lastName, belonging, country) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement stmt = this.dbConn.prepareStatement(query1);
        stmt.setInt(1,0);
        stmt.setString(2,"default"); //Yes, it's correct with "default"
        stmt.setString(3,"default");
        stmt.setString(4,"default");
        stmt.setString(5,"default");
        //stmt.executeUpdate();
        stmt.executeUpdate(query1, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        int key=0;
        if ( rs.next() ) {
            key = rs.getInt(1);
        }
        String query2 = "INSERT INTO authentication (id, address, password, user_id, login_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
        stmt = this.dbConn.prepareStatement(query2);
        stmt.setInt(1,0);
        stmt.setString(2,"default");
        stmt.setString(2,password);
        stmt.setInt(2,key);
        stmt.setString(2,userid);
        stmt.executeUpdate();
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Let me explain: I would like to execute two queries and the second one need the key that is generated in the first query (I need the primary key of the table "user" because user-authentication is a 1:1 relationship).

So:

1. Is this the correct way to execute more than one query?
2. Am I missing something with the returning key? Because if I run ONLY executeUpdate() and I comment every row below it the method works fine, but when I run the code in the example (with the first executeUpdate() commented) I get false (only false, no exception). Do I have to check something in my database?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I found a solution. It was an error in columns and not in the method for getting the generated key itself. I will choose Joop Eggen's answer for the improvements that he showed me. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what your actual problem is.  I would comment that if the two inserts are closely related from a logical point of view, you might want to run both of them inside a transaction.  This way, if either one fails, you can rollback the entire transaction and not end up with weirdness in your database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the problem is that I can't get the generated key. If I execute query with  `PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` the code exits with false instead of true, but the query is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of improvements needed.

```
String query1 = "INSERT INTO user (firstName, lastName, belonging, country)"
        + " VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
String query2 = "INSERT INTO authentication (address, password, user_id, login_id)"
        + " VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
try (PreparedStatement stmt1 = this.dbConn.prepareStatement(query1,
                PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        stmt2 = this.dbConn.prepareStatement(query2)) {
    stmt1.setString(1, "default");
    stmt1.setString(2, "default");
    stmt1.setString(3, "default");
    stmt1.setString(4, "default");
    stmt1.executeUpdate();
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt1.getGeneratedKeys())  {
        if (rs.next()) {
            int userid = rs.getInt(1);
            stmt2.setString(1, "default");
            stmt2.setString(2, password);
            stmt2.setInt(3, key);
            stmt2.setString(4, userid);
            stmt2.executeUpdate();
            return true;
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
return false;
```

1. Try-with-resources close automatically, also on exception and return.
2. You have two prepared statements to close.
3. The executeUpdate with the SQL is for the parents class Statement, and does disrespect the parameter settings. You chose that for the generated keys parameter, but that goes into Connection.prepareStatement.
4. (SQL) The generated keys should not be listed/quasi-inserted.
5. It is debatable whether one should catch the SQLException here. `throws SQLException` is what works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the improvements, it looks cleaner in this way. Anyway the problem was in the columns and not in the method itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'll advise you have a `username` field in your `user` table so after inserting you can simply do a `Select id from user Where username...`

Comment: But why wouldn't getting the generated key be equally, if not more effective?

Comment: since `username` is unique and it is being passed into the method it can never be wrong. By getting generated keys if you have large number of requests at the same time it 'might' be problematic

Comment: Using a primary key or a username seems to same to me, and actually getting the generated key might even be faster than doing a formal query for the username.